# Fetch all scheduled messages from a telegram group using the telethon library

Tags: python, telethon

How can I fetch all scheduled messages from my client in a particular group? I know how to access to messages that the client already send but I'm not able to find the scheduled ones.

I'm currently running a python application client and I am using telethon

Comment: Why was this closed as offtopic? It is a perfectly reasonable question to ask about `telethon` usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GetScheduledHistoryRequest` to do so https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_scheduled_history.html

from the example :

```
result = client(functions.messages.GetScheduledHistoryRequest(
    peer='username',
    hash=0
    ))
print(result.stringify())
```

Comment: Thanks. This works.. I can fetch them but.. how can I delete or edit those scheduled messages? The client.delete_messages doesn't do anything with them .

Comment: if it works why didn't you chose it as the accepted answer lol. anyway you can use https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/delete_scheduled_messages.html to delete. delete_messages is only for normal messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a message has been sent via schedule just check is `from_schedule` parameter.

```
Message.from_schedule
```

This will return `True` or `False`